# Archiving C# Solutions - deleting the obj folder

Tags: c#, solution

If I want to archive C# solutions and I just want to store the code I have written, I can delete the bin folder to save space. Are there any other folders such as the obj folder I can delete without impacting the solution if I ever decide to come back to it?

I tried looking through the obj folder and there doesn't seem to be anything I need to save. But I'm no expert so I thought I should ask some people that are.